# How to enforce user permissions in hawtio for standalone activemq

Tags: activemq-classic, hawtio

With Activemq 5.11 I was able to configure the users and groups so multiple users can log in based on the hawtio role that was set. However, read/write permissions are not enforced once in the hawtio console. Any user can perform any function. i.e. purge any queue, send to any destination.

Does anyone know of a way to enforce permissions in the hawtio web console using activemq standalone? I have only been able to find solutions using Karaf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RBAC of hawtio is tied into Karaf, so you cannot do this with standard ActiveMQ. Its using the RBAC of Karaf [1] to enforce the permissions, and ActiveMQ out of the box does not have any RBAC.

The hawtio ActiveMQ plugin has a setting in the preference where you can configure the username/password that is being used to send. So even if you can click the send button, then its that user that is used to send, and ActiveMQ can be configured to deny that user.

ActiveMQ has a security plugin you can configure [2]

[1] - https://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest/users-guide/monitoring.html

[2] - http://activemq.apache.org/security.html

Comment: Setting up the jaas security plugin does work to block sends, thank you.  I can still perform JMX functions although the users jmx.access is set to readonly. I am blocked from performing the same function in jconsole.